# How to fix "Could not show link Operation not supported"?

Tags: desktop-environment, applications-database

Here is what I see:

[image: Crude Do Not Enter sign and warning]

Here is when it happens: after clicking a link, in some, but not all,
programs, on GNU/Linux, the only computer I own.

You **cannot** blame me for not knowing more. In fact, I cannot even find a single tag
to tag this post.

Comment: (i) *When* did that start happening? (ii) *What* did you do just before these errors started happening? (iii) *Which* desktop environment do you use?

Comment: And (iv) what happens when you right-click on one of those icons?

Comment: This is odd, because I changed browsers and this didn’t happen.  Many people change browsers…

Comment: (i) For many years [spoiler: ever since I uninstalled chromium, and then installed  chrome on my system, but forgot to update the file mentioned below] (ii) Innocently clicked a link. (iii) Google says to echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP, which gives nothing. (iv) All I saw was a close button... and as expected, right clicking does nothing.

Comment: The chrome installer must not update mimetypes.

Answer (score 0):

Calm down. There is [no reasonable way](https://github.com/hellosiyan/Viewnior/issues/126), for you, the average user, to know what is causing the problem. Yes, all most users can do is complain to the authors of the particular app that emits the message. But as you saw over the years, the problem is not particular to a single app.

**One** solution is to

```
$ ls /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
```

and decide on your favorite one of the hopefully many shown, and stick it in
your `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file, as I have done
in the following example with `google-chrome-unstable.desktop`,
(which I found on my system, but may not be on yours):

```
[Default Applications]
text/html=google-chrome-unstable.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome-unstable.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome-unstable.desktop
x-scheme-handler/webcal=google-chrome-unstable.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. That fixed it. You are so smart. But how did you know?

Comment: that comment to yourself about yourself is cringe, dude

Comment: He didn't know. He assumed, but he didn't know. --Astor Clement & Ernest P. Worrel

Comment: What the heck is going on here? Am i living in a cuckoo clock - Homer J. Simpson

Comment: It said, "Answer your own question."  So, having a split personality, we did.